# returning observable values on another observable event Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I am writing a code which will fetch a set of Urls, and when they are successfully fetched, then an endpoint will be constructed out of them and an API will be called which will return data appropriately. What I am trying to do looks roughly like this

```
 getUrls(): Subscription {
  return this.common.getUrls().subscribe((data) => {
  this.urls = data;
},
  (error) => { },
  (): Observable<any> => {
    const _getUrl = this.urls.baseUrl + this.urls.someEndpoint;
    return this.http.get<any>(_getUrl);
  }
);
```

}

I am not sure whether this is the right way to solve the above problem. Please suggest how to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Observables are streams so I would suggest you chain your calls rather than following a promise based chains, I'm not sure how your code works but something similar to this should work.

```
getUrls()
.map(data=> data.urls)
.switchMap(urls => {
    const _getUrl = this.urls.baseUrl + this.urls.someEndpoint;
    return this.http.get<any>(_getUrl);
}).subscribe(urlResponse => {
 // do whatever with this response
});
```

Avoid putting observables within other observables, also I have not tested the above line but I'm sure it should point you towards the right direction.